# Import npm package with AMD API structure inside Vite esnext project

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, vite, amd, azure-devops-extensions

I'm developing an Azure DevOps extension and for that I must use packages azure-devops-extension-sdk and azure-devops-extension-api. I'm using svelte with typescript and when I'm trying to import the sdk, I'm getting this error `ReferenceError: define is not defined`. Currently typescript is set to target esnext and module esnext. I really don't want to change my typescript compiler options to AMD just because of this one package, so that's not an option for me.

I'm not really sure whether something like this is even possible with Vite, because so far I didn't find any solutions to this. I know it is possible with webpack or react-scripts, so I think it should be manageable with Vite too.

Did anyone come across a similar problem? If so, I would really appreciate any suggestions.

I came up with a few crude solutions that I tried, but they are not ideal at best.
I tried to use requirejs, didn't really work for me.
Then just cloned the source into git submodule, that kind of worked until a point, when the source tried to import this `import { getAccessToken, getService } from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";` inside src/Common/Client.ts

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share the code so that the community can help you answer the question: please see [how to create a minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).